# Create tablespace in gcloud sql instances

Tags: postgresql, database, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I had created one PostgreSQL instance under gcloud database.

Using default user (postgres) i want to create a tablespace but its not allowing me to create, says permission doesn't exist

Can we create custom tablespaces with gcloud database instances ?

Answer (score 2):

> Can we create custom tablespaces with gcloud database instances ?

The short answer is **no**. To create custom tablespaces within Cloud SQL instances running PostgreSQL you will need to have **SUPER USER** permissions.

The reason why you can not give to yourself **SUPER USER** permission is because Cloud SQL instances are fully managed.

As seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users#superuser_restrictions) you have some restrictions since you can not give to yourself the permission specified.

Nonetheless, if you would like to have tablespaces you could setup your own PostgreSQL database within GCE instances.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres) you could see a tutorial on how to set up PostgreSQL on Compute Engine. Doing so will give you **complete control over** everything regarding PostgreSQL and the underlying instance running it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info.